# Insight into the feasibility of two REST API designs

Tags: node.js, mongodb, rest, mongoose, api-design

I have developed several REST APIs in the past and am currently working on building a new one for an in-house software solution at our company. I have chosen the MEAN stack to build this and Mongoose to manage schema design and data layer validation. Good design, durability and extensibility are on the top of my list.

API will be consumed by our in-house Angular app, Android app and who knows what else, it might one day be consumed by our PHP website, or perhaps farther into the future we may provide the platform to other businesses.

I am currently weighing two designs:

- **General purpose**: Provide access to all but the restricted CRUD access to the API consumer as per authentication, provide custom endpoints for complex requests. Kinda like [Parse](https://www.parse.com/).
- **Restricted**: Have used this in the past. API consumer presents a requirement which is then fulfilled by the server in the form of an endpoint.

**General purpose Design**

API consumer can craft queries as per the front-end requirement flexibly while very complex compilations are moved into a custom endpoint. Global limits in place (eg: 100 records can be returned at most), each authenticated system user type can be restricted schema and record level access.

```
'use strict';

module.exports = function (app) {

            // Api routing
            var api = require('../controllers/api.controller.js');

            /**
             * Cental API router
             */

            app.route('/api/create')
                .post(api.create);

            app.route('/api/read')
                .get(api.read);

            app.route('/api/update')
                .put(api.update);

            app.route('/api/remove')
                .delete(api.remove);

            app.route('/api/dashboard/:country/:date') //Complex endpoint
                .get(api.dashboard);
    };
```

Example response of a create call:

```
{
   "response":[
      {
         "_id":"54f703531c3757fe23923250",
         "entity_id":3,
         "customer_id":104,
         "base_grand_total":15,
         "total_qty_ordered":1,
         "total_item_count":1,
         "customer_gender":1,
         "shipping_address_id":6,
         "quote_id":8,
         "increment_id":"200000089",
         "order_currency_code":"AED",
         "country_id":"AE",
         "status":"pending_receiving"
      }
   ],
   "numberAffected":1,
   "result":"created",
   "dataModel":"Orders",
   "errorMsg":null,
   "error":0
}
```

Use case: deleting a user using AngularJS.

```
            var req = {
                method: 'DELETE',
                url: '/api/remove',
                data: {query: {'_id': id}, dataModel: 'Users' // 'Orders', 'Products' 'Etc'},
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                }
            };

            $http(req).success(function (res) {

                $scope.users.splice(rowIndex,1);
                console.log(res);

            }).error(function (res) {

                console.log(res);
            });
```

**Restricted design**

Getting client requirement and providing an endpoint. Would probably look something like this:

```
public function userProfileAction()
public function createPostAction()
public function getPostsByUserAction()
public function getPostsByDistanceAction()
public function getPostsByFollowedUsersAction()
public function getPostsByVenueAction()
public function getPostsLikedByUserAction()
public function deletePostAction()
public function reportPostAction()
public function recommendPostAction()
public function followUserAction()
public function likePostAction()
```

---

To prevent this question from going sideways I want to be specific and only stick to pros and cons of each approach.

The pro I see for the general purpose design is that it's not tightly coupled with the server so we can build a lot of functionality without back and coding an endpoint again and again. The con being, if I have the same query in 4 API consumers, I need to go change the query in each one if I ever decide to make a change. For the restricted design it's vice versa.

Can you guys point out more that I may be missing, pros and cons, things I should watch out for? Is there a security concern or a major design flaw I may be over looking.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are significant pros and cons:

### Pros of general purpose API:

- It's general purpose and meant to provide access to all legal functionality that a client is allowed to do.
- Clients can likely use the general purpose API to solve problems in the future that they haven't even yet known they had a need for.
- There will likely be many fewer requests for new API features as the client needs evolve because general access has already been offered.

### Cons of general purpose API:

- It's probably more work to code and very likely more work to test.
- Security or access control issues may be more complex.
- Potential for abuse by unintended clients is higher.
- Clients may have to "build" their own layer on top of your API by piecing together several API calls to get the specific function they want.
- The API may not offer a solution as efficiently as could be done with an endpoint designed specifically to the specification of a given client need (in other words, the client may have to use multiple API requests or may have fetch and look at more data than is optimal).

The pros/cons of the restricted API are pretty much the opposites of these.

---

One middle ground is to have the client submit a detailed specification for what functionality they need access to and then design a general purpose API, but only initially implement the pieces that are needed to solve the client's current problems.

This gives you a general purpose design and sets you up well for expanding access to other areas in the future in a logical, planned manner.  But, you don't implement or have to test more than the client really needs right now (which is often a business desire).  And, you can be 100% sure that your general purpose implementation subset meets the client's current needs because you can test it against their specification of needs.

---

Going all the way to a general purpose API without having the client list their specific and current needs runs the risk of accidentally not covering everything the client needs.  And, it likely spends time implementing and testing lots of things that aren't currently needed.

Going all the way to a restricted API that lines up API calls with each specific client specification request makes it hard to ever have an overall thoughtful API design (because one was never designed from the beginning and you just end up with hodgepodge of client requests).

Presumably, you can see that neither extreme is likely ideal.